# Masked (hidden) failures copying large folder with File Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, file-transfer

When I start copying a very large folder (say 40 GB) in Windows 7 File Explorer, the rate of progress indicates that it may take hours to complete.  So I leave it overnight, only to discover in the morning that it still claims to be trying to copy (it has failed but still appears to be in progress).

Is there a way to copy a large folder with high confidence that it will be successfully completed, or at least that it will conclude and display an error message if there is a problem?

Comment: Last time I used Windows, it didn't even know if the destination had sufficient space for the file until it returned a 'disk full' error, half way through. Hopefully that has improved since Win7... but ...

Comment: @Tetsujin it really is a pain to get a large folder to copy via file explorer. This issue is not acknoledged too well. Using File explorer for large folders should be a no no to put it blunetly.

Comment: You've got a legit question buried in this, but it's worded in an off-topic way.  It invites discussion, invites dispute about whether File Explorer is actually problematic, and asks for opinion on what's best.  I'm voting to close on that basis, but will retract the vote if you can improve the question.  Just state the problem you're facing and ask for a solution to it.

Comment: @fixer1234 I have changed the title since.

Comment: Copying from one drive to another drive will be much faster than copying to the same drive.  When copying to the same drive, the drive needs to keep finding, and moving between, the source and destination locations.  If the folder contains a huge number of tiny files, it also needs to store directory information for each one.  So that will take much longer than copying a few extremely large files.  Huge folders won't be copied instantaneously, but 40 GB shouldn't take hours, even under the worst conditions (unless you are doing another drive-intensive, (cont'd)

Comment: or memory-intensive, task simultaneously.  If it is taking hours, it may be because the drive is starting to fail, or at least has a lot of corruption.  In that case, it spends a lot of time trying to reread bad areas and relocate data from bad areas.  The symptom you experienced indicates that it may be wise to run chkdsk on the drive to clean it up.  If the drive has SMART support, check its statistics to see if it's starting to fail.

Comment: This could also be caused by the SSD cache being saturated. This video explains it in layman's terms. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OffzVc7ZB-o

Answer (score 0):

Using windows file explorer to copy a large folder is, indeed, not very helpful for two reasons.

- The main reason is that the file copy may fail for one reason or another, but it never returns and it will appear as if copying is still in progress where, in fact, it'ts just stuck. This can waste a lot of time of user.
- If it failed due to error, it doesn't tell why it failed, what was the problem.

For example a file copy may fail because amid 40 GB data, there was one invalid shortcut where the target was missing. This will fail the copy but user will neer know and it will appear as if the copying is still in progress. There could be other reasons of failures that we we wouldn't know.

**Solutions:**

1. It's best to copy large folders on command line and use `xcopy'.  The benfit is that if it fails, it will return immediatly and you will know. That said it will still fail with above situation (invalid shortcut) but will error out correctly.
2. The best Selection is to deploy a blind copy which doesn't care about the files but copy bits to bits. The best tools are `scp` or `rsync` but they are not readily available on Windows.

**Using SCP on Windows**

Install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) on Windows and use `scp`command from its shell the following way assuming to copy c:\BigFolder to a USB drive F:\BigFolderBackup/

```
scp -r /cygdrive/c/BigFolder/ /cygdrive/f/BigFolderBackup/
```

Where -r is for recurrsive copy which means copy all subfolders and their files.

**Update 1**

As noted by Scott in comments, since its copy on local machine so `cp` will do as well. Syntax is essentially identical.

Another scenario I came across is when a folder contain a file where I didn't had permssions to read. Our IT department doesn't allow users to run CCleaner utility so read permission is disabled on it.

I used `cp` this time and it performed nicely. It reported appropriate error on this file (didn't copy it) but didn't halt the copy operation and it continued with copying everything else. Another reason that this approach wins.

**Update 2**

I discovered `scp` (and probably `cp`) modifies file ownership which can cause problem with read/write access. Adding `p` flag should address that as noted in this [article](https://www.web24.com.au/tutorials/retaining-directory-permissions-using-scp). Another way is to use `rsync` with `-o` and `-g` flags as noted in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144599/136316) answer to preserve ownership of files.

Comment: If you have Cygwin, and you're not copying from one machine to another, why no just use ``cp`` (instead of `scp`)?

Comment: @Scott I guess that too, might be better in this case. It just didn't come on my radar since I had only used scp in the past